# How to select only textboxes from a bunch of dynamically created elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a bunch of form elements like `textbox,textarea,checkbox and dropdownlists` dynamically and i want to select only `textboxes` whose id ends with some value. How can we accomplish this in `jQuery`.

P.S. I know how to select an element whose id ends with by using 
`$( "[attribute$='value']" )` selector. But here i have apply some kind of filter to select only text boxes.Below is the final html output rendered after the element creation. Now how can i select only `textbox` with id `txtFirstnamefeedback1`.

```
<input type="text" id="txtFirstnamefeedback1">
<input type="text" id="txtLastnamefeedback1">
<input type="text" id="txtSurnamefeedback1">
<p id="pfavblogliteraltextfeedback1">Select your interested blog </p>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1favBlogfeedback1" value="Bike">ASP.NET Web Forms</ br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2favBlogfeedback1" value="Car">ASP.NET MVC
```

Comment: $('input[type=textbox]');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add type in selector, [:text](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) will filter out only the textboxes i.e. all html elemnent where `input` type is `text`

```
$(":text[attribute$='value']")
```

Your selector would be like

```
$(":text[id$='feedback1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select textbox as well as textarea

```
$('input[type=text], textarea')
```